# What is the error app publishing on the Google developer console?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-developers-console

I want to upload an app to the Google Developer Console, but when I upload the app, it gives the following error:

You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme

[See the screenshot I uploaded here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0wmC.png)
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are building the 'release' variant, after signing it with an upload key. Also, I would recommend you sign in for Google App Signing, which will certainly solve these issues and keep your signing key secure as well. The schema problems will be taken care of by Google itself then. There is an option in the console to opt-in to Play Signing

Answer (score 0):

In the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog, after you select the jks key stroke path, you should see a page with 2 options

1. Build Variants: debug or release
2. Signature Versions: V1 (Jar Signature) and/or V2 (Full APK signature)

You should make sure V2 is checked when build.